# index.php/news 404 not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a beginner in CodeIgniter and I am following the tutorial in the official site. I am done with static pages. When tried News example and opend the link `index.php/news` it is showing the msg 404 not found.

**application/controllers/News.php**

```
<?php

class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('news_model');
                $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function index()
        {
                $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
                $data['title'] = 'News archive';

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }

        public function view($slug = NULL)
        {
                $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
                if (empty($data['news_item']))
                {
                        show_404();
                }

                $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
}
```

**application/views/news/index.php**

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

        <h3><?php echo $news_item['title']; ?></h3>
        <div class="main">
                <?php echo $news_item['text']; ?>
        </div>
        <p><a href="<?php echo site_url('news/'.$news_item['slug']); ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**application/views/news/view.php**

```
<?php
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news_item['text'];
```

**application/config/routes.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Comment: how about using `news/index`?

Comment: it displays object not found

Comment: `$route['news'] = 'news';` remove this and check

Comment: @Abdulla no change same output

Comment: I am trying in local

Comment: .htaccess is located in views folder

Comment: @DharanBro i posted answer where to post

Comment: Put `default_controller` at beginning of routs. `(:any)` need to be at the `routes.php` file end, always.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$route['news'] = 'news';
```

To

```
$route['news'] = 'news/index';
```

Comment: index call automatically

Answer (score 0):

### **Error is**

> This should be

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

this

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

---

and place this on `.htaccess`(Outside application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I also tried creating a file  views/pages/news.php and copied the contents in views/news/index.php and thentried opening index.php/news it displayed the page with PHP errors